# UnicodeDecodeError when using python 2.7 code on python 3.7 with cPickle

Tags: python, encoding, deserialization, pickle

I am trying to use cPickle on a .pkl file constructed from a "parsed" .csv file. The parsing is undertaken using a pre-constructed python toolbox, which has recently been ported to python 3 from python 2 (https://github.com/GEMScienceTools/gmpe-smtk)

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
from smtk.parsers.esm_flatfile_parser import ESMFlatfileParser
parser=ESMFlatfileParser.autobuild("Database10","Metadata10","C:/Python37/TestX10","C:/Python37/NorthSea_Inc_SA.csv")
import cPickle
sm_database = cPickle.load(open("C:/Python37/TestX10/metadatafile.pkl","r"))
```

It returns the following error:

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 44: character maps to <undefined>`

From what I can gather, I need to specify the encoding of my .pkl file to enable cPickle to work but I do not know what the encoding is on the file produced from the parsing of the .csv file, so I can't use cPickle to currently do so.

I used the sublime text software to find it is "hexadecimal", but this is not an accepted encoding format in Python 3.7 is it not?

If anyone knows how to determine the encoding format required, or how to make hexadecimal encoding usable in Python 3.7 their help would be much appreciated.

P.s. the modules used such as "ESMFlatfileparser" are part of a pre-constructed toolbox. Considering this, is there a chance I may need to alter the encoding in some way within this module also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is opening the file in *text* mode (`'r'`), but it should be *binary* mode (`'rb'`).

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.load) for `pickle.load` (emphasis mine):

> [The] file can be an on-disk file **opened for binary reading**, an io.BytesIO object, or any other custom object that meets this interface.

Since the file is being opened in binary mode there is no need to provide an encoding argument to `open`.  It may be necessary to provide an encoding argument to `pickle.load`.  From the same documentation:

> Optional keyword arguments are fix_imports, encoding and errors, which are used to control compatibility support for pickle stream generated by Python 2. If fix_imports is true, pickle will try to map the old Python 2 names to the new names used in Python 3. The encoding and errors tell pickle how to decode 8-bit string instances pickled by Python 2; these default to ‘ASCII’ and ‘strict’, respectively. The encoding can be ‘bytes’ to read these 8-bit string instances as bytes objects. Using encoding='latin1' is required for unpickling NumPy arrays and instances of datetime, date and time pickled by Python 2.

This ought to prevent the `UnicodeDecodeError`:

```
sm_database = cPickle.load(open("C:/Python37/TestX10/metadatafile.pkl","rb"))
```

Comment: could the change from text mode to binary mode result in the error `ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'` when attempting to use a print function which previously worked in the Python 2 version?