# Why is opening .pkl file showing this unicode error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle, python-unicode

I'm trying to open this `.pkl` file. I keep getting this error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 772: character maps to <undefined>
```

Here's my code:

```
import pickle

with open(r"C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\Abhishek\STATS Data\test_data_1.pkl ", 'r') as f:
    data = pickle.load(f)
print(data)
```

Trying to specify encoding as `encoding = "utf-8"` throws this up:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: You have to open pickle files in binary mode: `with open("...", "rb") as f:`

Comment: I tried that. Here's the error:
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x91 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: Did you use binary mode when you created the `pkl` file? `'wb'`

Comment: I didn't create the file. I have received the data from someone else.

Comment: Then make sure they used the same version of Python.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about that? Does pickling change from version to version?

Comment: Does this help - note the references to using extra arguments when deserialising from Python2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55392418/5320906

Comment: Nope, I still get the same error. I can't understand what's causing it.